# a variable in HTML

Tags: html

in the form action i have the following line\

```
<form action="{URL}" method="post" target="_self" id="xxx" name="xxx">
```

when rendered in the browser it becomes

```
action="/abc/17224_pb/HTTP/index.php"
```

this is just HTML. I cannot see anywhere the {URL} has been defined and anyway you cannot have variables in HTML (can you?)

i thought it might be jquery but it would need to be in a script ??

Where does it come from? How is it defined?

This code is not really in a framework but we do have some Zend framework code around.

Edit: Doh! templating engine. Well smarty is definitely not there but some of the Zend framework is included in the project so i am going to assume that is where it is originating.

I traced the build of the page and Zend is the only thing included that could be the engine.
Thanks guys.

Comment: You may have just discovered an easter egg variable that the W3C sneaked in while designing HTML!

Comment: i thought it was more like a Cuckoo's egg. I mean i should have known from the curly braces but it's been a while since i did any Smarty etc and i just never though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your html must be running on some sort of template engine that replaces that token with the real url.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there is a **[template engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29)** being used such as **[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)** or some custom template mechanism or **[many of them out there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29)**.

Answer (score 1):

looks like something a templating engine would replace with the appropriate content

Answer (score 0):

search through your code for html-file name, there should be template-engine call or something :)